# ModelNotFoundException when passing Model Object in Event constructor

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

This is my controller:

```
$transaction = new ProductTransactionLog();
Event::fire(new SendResponseToProduct($response, $transaction));
```

This is event class (SendResponseToProduct):

```
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use App\Models\ProductTransactionLog;

class SendResponseToProduct extends Event
{
    use SerializesModels;

    public $response = [];
    public $transaction;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     */
    public function __construct($response = [], ProductTransactionLog $product_transaction)
    {
        // dd($transaction);
        $this->response = $response;
        $this->transaction = $product_transaction;
        // dd($this->transaction);
    }
}
```

This is in the EventServiceProvider:

```
protected $listen = [
        'App\Events\SendResponseToProduct' => [
            'App\Listeners\ResponseToProductListener',
        ],
    ];
```

When I run the controller, i.e when I fire the Event, I get this weird error:

> NotFoundHttpException in Handler.php line 46: No query results for
>   model [App\Models\ProductTransactionLog].

When I `dd` in the Event constructor, I get the object. When I uncomment `dd`, I get the error again.

When I `dd` in the Listener class, I get this same error. It does not reach the Listener class.

What is it that I am missing here?

Comment: please add the controller method definition with signature and all code in it that you are routing to.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `SerializesModels` trait in `SendResponseToProduct` for a queue (probably sync). It always serialize and deserialize all fields.

This trait especially check weather the serialized field (in this example is: public $transaction;) is instance of a `ModelIdentifier` (serialized field of a `Model` object is - becasue `Model` class is instance of `QueueableEntity` interface). If is then he trying to find model's record in DB by `id` which in this case you don't have at this model because you've just create it without any data.

So what you can do is to remove `SerializesModels` trait if you're not using queue - or not to passing an empyt model here.